# Error performing query INSERT INTO with Active Record Pattern

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord

I'm trying to implement the Active Record Pattern with PHP; I have the following code

```
<?php

// define 'MySQL' class
class users{
  private $result;

  public function __construct($host='localhost',$user='user',$password='password',$database='pruebalabo'){
    // connect to MySQL and select database
    if(!($conId = @mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root",""))){
       throw new Exception('Error connecting to the server');
    }
    if(!mysql_select_db("pruebalabo",$conId)){
       throw new Exception('Error selecting database');
    }
  }

  // run SQL query
  public function query($query){
    if(!$this->result=mysql_query($query)){
      throw new Exception('Error performing query '.$query);
    }
  }
  // fetch one row
  public function fetchRow(){
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($this->result)){
      return $row;
    }
    return false;
  }
  // fetch all rows
  public function fetchAll($table='users'){
     $this->query('SELECT * FROM '.$table);
     $rows=array();
     while($row=$this->fetchRow()){
        $rows[]=$row;
     }
     return $rows;
  }
  // insert row
  public function insert($params=array(),$table='default_table'){
     $sql='INSERT INTO '.$table.' ('.implode(',', array_keys($params)).') VALUES ('.implode("','",array_values($params)).')';
     $this->query($sql);
  }

}


try{
  // connect to MySQL and select a database
  $db=new users("host","root","","pruebalabo");
  $result=$db->fetchAll('users');
  foreach($result as $row){
     echo $row['firstname'].' '.$row['lastname'].' '.$row['email'].'<br />';
  }

  // connect to MySQL and select a database
  $db=new users("127.0.0.1","root","","pruebalabo");
  // insert new row into selected MySQL table
  $db->insert(array('firstname'=>'Sebas','lastname'=>'Guajardo','email'=>'tururus@domain.com'),'users');

}

catch(Exception $e){
  echo $e->getMessage();
  exit();
}

?>
```

When I try to run the code, though, I get an error with the following line

```
$db->insert(array('firstname'=>'Sebas','lastname'=>'Guajardo','email'=>'tururus@domain.com'),'users');
```

I don't see an error in the syntax, and I took the example pretty much straight from [this](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Using-the-Active-Record-Pattern-with-PHP-and-MySQL/3/) page. The name of my database (implemented on MySQL) is 'pruebalabo', and the name of the table is 'users'.

EDIT: Fixed mistake pointed out. Still getting an error.

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: @andrewsi Error performing query INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES (Sebas','Guajardo','tururus@domain.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your insert function as below

```
public function insert($params=array(),$table='default_table'){
     $sql='INSERT INTO '.$table.' ('.implode(',', array_keys($params)).') VALUES ('.'\''.implode("','",array_values($params)).'\''.')';
     $this->query($sql);
  }
```

Comment: Man, I can't believe it was something so stupid. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

Your function includes a variable `$firstname`, but that variable doesn't exist. It looks like you intend to do `implode(',' , array_keys($params))` to supply the array keys as column names while you implode the array values into the `VALUES()` list.

```
 public function insert($params=array(),$table='default_table'){
   // Pass the array keys as column names to match the VALUES().
   // I have surrounded them all in `backquotes` in the implode() here
   $sql="INSERT INTO ".$table." (`" . implode('`,`', array_keys($params)) . "`) VALUES ('".implode("','",array_values($params))."')";
   $this->query($sql);
 }
```

Always check for success or failure in a `mysql_query()` call, and on failure inspect the output of `mysql_error()`.

Note: we assume you are safely escaping the values in `$params` before passing them to your query in cases where they are not hard-coded as they are in this one.

Comment: I changed the line to `$sql='INSERT INTO '.$table.' ('.implode(',', array_keys($params)).') VALUES ('.implode("','",array_values($params)).')'; $this->query($sql);` but I'm still getting an error.

Comment: @AnaAmeer Quoting changed above. You were short one single quote surrounding the outer VALUES

Comment: Yes, I see that now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This function

```
public function insert($params=array(),$table='default_table'){
     $sql='INSERT INTO '.$table.' ('.$firstName.') VALUES ('.implode("','",array_values($params)).')';
     $this->query($sql);
  }
```

uses a variable that isn't defined "$firstName" and take in care that the values you specify should correspond with the columns you specify in ('.$firstName.')

Use this code for the function, the problem seems to be a missing "'" character:

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO $table (".implode(',', array_keys($params))
 .") VALUES ('".implode("','",array_values($params))."')"; 
$this->query($sql);
```

Regards

Comment: sorry, that was a line that was modified and forgot to change back. I changed it to `$sql='INSERT INTO '.$table.' ('.implode(',', array_keys($params)).') VALUES ('.implode("','",array_values($params)).')';
     $this->query($sql);` but I'm still getting an error.

Comment: I update the reply with the new code to use. Seems that was missing some ' characters